# is or are to blame?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, coordination

Should **is** or **are** be used in the following?

> A lack of health care systems and access to healthy food options **is / are** also to blame for their health issues.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use 'is'. ***A*** (one) lack (singular) of two things is being blamed, of health care systems and access to healthy food options. To use 'are' would be to say that a lack of healthcare systems is to blame for health issues, and access to healthy food options is to blame for health issues. The latter does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

> *A lack of [health care systems] and [access to healthy food options] is /
>   are also to blame for their health issues.*

The subject is a noun phrase headed by the singular noun "lack", which has the *of* preposition phrase as complement. The head of the PP, "of", contains a coordination of complements, as bracketed, but this has no effect on the number of the NP which is determined by the singular "lack".

Which means that the verb-form should also be singular, i.e. "is".